# Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I get a `Conversion failed` error when converting `DateTime` from character string, any help?

```
sqlcon.Open();
sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select [Uzsak_Nr],[Preke],[Uzsak_Kiekis],[Gaut_Kiekis],[MyDate],[Gaut_Data] from emp where MyDate between '" + TextBoxData1  + "'  and  '" + TextBoxData2 + "' ", sqlcon);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
da.Fill(dt);
GridViewRodyti.DataSource = dt;
GridViewRodyti.DataBind();
sqlcon.Close();
```

Comment: What are the values of your TextBoxData1 and TextBoxData2 variables? Are they strings?

Comment: No i slelected it from callendar control

TextBoxData1.Text = CalendarRodyti.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        this.CalendarRodyti.Visible = false;

Comment: That's great but you would be best to show the code which populates those variables. Its likely that the TexBoxDataX variables are in a date format that your database cannot parse. What DB are you using?

Comment: Im using sql server express 2012 and i want to select tada beetween one date and other and those dates i want to choose from textboxes and those text boxes are connected with callendar when i select date on callendar the text wrotes on textboxdate1 and so on.. Sry for my bad english grama :( i hope u understand what i want to say :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has got [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) written all over it...

Use **parameterized queries** e.g.

```
var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select [Uzsak_Nr],[Preke],[Uzsak_Kiekis],[Gaut_Kiekis],[MyDate],[Gaut_Data] from emp where MyDate between '@startDate' and '@endDate'", sqlcon);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", DateTime.Parse(TextBoxData1)));
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endDate", DateTime.Parse(TextBoxData2)));
```

Your issue is probably due to an invalid date format, if you use `SqlParameter` and convert the string to a `DateTime` it should take care of the conversion for you.

Comment: user1945561 is not asking for advice on how to make their code more secure

Comment: @KevinBrydon maybe not, but I am *giving* the advice anyway. Not only will it make his code more secure but it will fix his conversion issue. The problem is trying to pass dates to SQL as strings is never a good idea due to potential localization issues. Best letting the framework do that for you.

Comment: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Comment: @user1945561 looks like you have an extra closing bracket somewhere in your code.

Comment: You probably have other issues. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tc5zwdf7(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @James It always grates when that happens!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you do it like this...

```
sqlcon.Open();
DateTime date1;
DateTime date2;
DateTime.TryParse(TextBoxData1.Text, out date1); //is TextBoxData1 a TextBox?
DateTime.TryParse(TextBoxData2.Text, out date2);


if (date1 != null && date2 != null) {    
    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(
      "select [Uzsak_Nr],[Preke],[Uzsak_Kiekis],[Gaut_Kiekis],[MyDate],[Gaut_Data] " +
      "from emp where MyDate between @dt1 and  @dt2 ", sqlcon);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", date1);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", date2);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridViewRodyti.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewRodyti.DataBind();
    sqlcon.Close();
}
```

Using parameterised queries is much nicer and doesn't run the risk of injection.

I have assumed you are using SQLServer.

Comment: @user1945561 If answer has solved your problem, please mark it as correct!